# How to get component name or the python from vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I use vue-router like：

```
export default new Router({
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  components: {
    navbar: Navbar,
    subnavbar: SubNavbar,
    main: WhoisPage   //********
  }
}
```

In my component WhoisPage.vue, I want to know the component path or the main module(which is //****** line) use which component?

How to do it with vue or vuex?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, there is no "components" property on vue-router.

You need to use "component" property to inject your shell component (in this case, it looks like WhoisPage) then you can call your sub-components to build your page inside your shell component.

If you want to change your sub-components based on route automatically, you can send their names as string and render in your shell-component.

```js
// in your router config.

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: WhoisPage,
      meta: {
        navbar: 'NavbarComponent'
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<!-- in your shell component, ofc your navbar needs to be imported -->

<component :is="$route.meta.navbar"></component>
```

Not sure i correctly answered what you need tho.